# Neo4jShell Facebook data import, cannot create relationships

Tags: neo4j

I followed the following post to test facebook friends of friends in Neo4j 2.0.1
http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/06/fun-with-facebook-in-neo4j_19.html

I am able to create the nodes successfully.. Auto Indexing is enabled
Here is the create node statement - `create (n{name:'User 123', type:'Facebook'});`
This works fine
When I create the relationships, I am getting this notification: "Nothing was created and No data Returned"

Here is the create Relationship statement

```
start n1=node:node_auto_index(name='User 123'),n2=node:node_auto_index(name='User XYZ') CREATE n1-[:IS_A_FRIEND_OF]->n2;
```

Any help is very much appreciated. I am new to `neo4j` and trying to get my hands dirty by learning some stuff.

Comment: check if your auto_indexing is turned on in server config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j 2.0 has a new feature called [schema indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graphdb-neo4j-schema.html#graphdb-neo4j-schema-indexes). For most use cases it's beneficial to use schema indexing instead of autoindexing.

For your example, I'd move the value of the `type` property to become a label.

First, create the index for property `name` based on label `Facebook`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Facebook(name)
```

The `CREATE` looks like:

```
CREATE (n:Facebook {name:'User 123'})
```

For creating the relationships use:

```
MATCH (n1:Facebook {name:'User 123'}),n2=(n2:Facebook {name:'User XYZ'}) 
CREATE n1-[:IS_A_FRIEND_OF]->n2
```

You might also look into Neo4j 2.0's new [MERGE](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html) statement.

Comment: That worked ..Thanks a lot..I will also take a look at Neo4j's new MERGE statement..Thanks again